# SlidingDrawer - Setting the open/close treshold

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am working with a sliding drawer and it works pretty well. This is how I defined it:

```
<SlidingDrawer              
         android:id="@+id/drawer2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:allowSingleTap="false"
         android:handle="@+id/handle2"
         android:content="@+id/content2">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/handle2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:src="@drawable/chargearrow"
             android:background="@drawable/rightroundedrectangle"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             android:paddingLeft="2px"
             android:paddingTop="6px"
             android:paddingBottom="5px">
         </ImageView>   

      <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/content2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" 
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:background="#FF444444"
             android:gravity="right"/>              

</SlidingDrawer>
```

As you can see, I defined it so that it does not open on click. However, you can still slide it around and it ends up opening when you cross some particular threshold in the screen. Is there anyway I can set that threshold? Is there a way by which I can lieten for when the handle crosses that threshold?

I know that the `SlidingDrawer` has methods:

- `setOnDrawerCloseListener()`
- `setOnDrawerScrollListener()`
- `setOnDrawerOpenListener()`

However, I don't know what I am supposed to do in these methods to set the threshold for when the `slidingDrawer` opens up or to listen for when it crosses the existing threshold?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: by the particular threshold u mean the limit after which it wont retract back inside right?

Comment: Urban - yes that is what I meant...